# Tensorflow: Elementwise-inversion of multiple matrices of different shape

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow

I have a set of differently-shaped matrices `M = (M_1, M_2, ... M_K)`. For efficiency purposes, I can store all of `M` into a single tensor of size `K x max(M_k.shape[0]) x max(M_k.shape[1])`. This works fine for doing things like batch matrix multiplication and elementwise additions. But what if I want to do elementwise divisions where the zero elements are ignored?

The best version of this I've come up with is:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
M = tf.constant(np.array([[1.,2.,0],[3.,4.,5.],[6.,0,0]]), tf.float32)
Minv = tf.select(tf.equal(M, 0), tf.zeros_like(M), tf.inv(M))
```

Is this the fastest way? Does `tf.select` still get accelerated well via a GPU?

Comment: Select certainly has [GPU kernels registered](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_op_select.cc#L149), so I doubt it will hurt performance much.

Comment: For anyone coming here later (like I did!) note that `select` has moved to `where`.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Tensorflow are you using?
`tf.select` is [deprecated](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c72d891418c326794a913cc13382c104255fe1f2/RELEASE.md).

You can use `tf.where`, here is an implementation below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
# precision 
eps = 1e-7
M = tf.constant(np.array([[1.,2.,0],[3.,4.,5.],[6.,0,0]]), tf.float32)
Minv = tf.where(tf.abs(M)>eps, 1/M, M)
Minv
```

where:

- `tf.abs(M)>eps` is the mask
- the second argument is the value if the mask is True
- the third arugment if the value of the mask is False